# JavaScript popup with delay

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, popup

What am I doing wrong here? A simple (test) div. I want it to pop up automatically with a delay.

```html
<div id="myModal">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">My Modal</p>
</div>

<script>
    function MyTest() {
        document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
        setTimeout(myModal, 3000);
    }
    var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close") [0];
    close.onclick = function() {
        myModal.style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";` inside `setTimeOut`.

```
<div id="myModal">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">My Modal</p>
</div>
    
<script>
    function MyTest() {
        document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
        }, 3000);
    }
    MyTest();
    
    var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close") [0];
    close.onclick = function() {
        myModal.style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Rupesh, thank you so much for your response. Your edit moves the "X" (close icon) inside the timeout function. This did not allow the PopUp to display at all. HOWEVER, you guided me to the correct answer. I moved the element "myModal" inside the timeout function and it works. Below is the change I made.

I've been playing with this for quite  while. Thanks again!
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    document.getElementById("myModal");
    setTimeout(function() {
    myModal.style.display = "block";
    }, 3000);